# Java create an array of object which the 40% of the array length should be object x the other 30% object z and 30% object y

Tags: java, arrays, object

I want to create an array of object which the 40% of the array length should be object x ,the other 30% object z and 30% object y.
so i generate random number for array length

```
int numb = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * 20);
```

for example if the random number is 10 the array length will be 10 and from that 10 i want the 4 elements be object x the other 3 element be object z and the other 3 element object y.How can i do that?

thanks for your time 
sorry for bad english

Comment: The most easy one would be 3 loops.

Comment: What are objects `x`, `y` and `z`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int numb = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * 20);
Object[] a = new Object[numb];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (i < (int)(a.length * 0.4))
        a[i] = x;
    else if (i >= (int)(a.length * 0.4) && i < (int)(a.length * 0.7))
        a[i] = y;
    else
        a[i] = z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you get your input about the max number of objects you can have .

```
 Class ObjectCount
 {
     String objectName; //class Name
     int  maxCount; // number of objects based on percentage
     int currentCount;
 } 



Create 
          HashMap<String,ObjectCount>map=new HashMap<>();
          List<Object>list; // This list has all the objects 
          Object[] arr=new Object[list.size()];//Assuming we have to fill this array
          int index=0;
          for(Object obj:list)
          {
          String className=obj o.getClass().getName()
           ObjectCount count=map.get("className");
            if(count.currentCount<maxCount) 
             {
              count.currentCount+=1;
              map.put(className,count);
              arr[index++]=obj;  
             }  
             else
             {
              // If you want throw some Exception
             }
          }
```